# How to log a static method in a static class when running a AZURE Function locally

Tags: .net, logging, static, azure-functions, .net-6.0

I have this static class:

```
public static class MyStaticClass {

  private static ILogger? _logger;

  public static void InitializeLogger(ILogger logger)
  {
      _logger = logger;
  }
   
      public static void GetResults(RequestModel request)
      {
          var err= request.body.results.select(c => c.errorMessage
           //what i want to do is something like:
                       foreach (var err in errors)
            {
                ILogger logger = new LoggerFactory().CreateLogger("MyStaticClass");
                InitializeLogger(logger);
                _logger?.LogInformation(err);
            }
      }

   }
```

however the line _logger?.LogInformation(err) does not write anything to my console, but this works in my other services that arent static. what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` then your logger in not setup correctly. Your method `new LoggerFactory().CreateLogger("MyStaticClass");` returns the instance of the logger but that logger is not enabled and has no providers. If you wanna log into the console you have to

1. Install `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console`
2. Configure your logger like this:

`var logger  = LoggerFactory.Create(builder => builder.AddConsole()).CreateLogger("MyStaticClass");`